# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-security, cxf

I upgraded my application's spring version from 3.2.10 to 4.3.16, and also my http-client to 4.3.3 from 4.2.1. While running my application, I am getting error page.

Comment: what kind of errors?

Comment: in catch block i am redirecting to error page.

Comment: in logs i am seeing java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.ProviderFactory

Comment: How did you solve this problem ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you try including the following dependency in your pom?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-bundle-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```